# Python's CFFI - Pass in floating point value #define directives to cdef()

Tags: python, c, python-cffi

CFFI's documentation says that it supports the use of constants and macros (like `#define`) in the `cdef` "provided the macro is defined to be an integer value", but it doesn't explicitly say that floating point constants are not supported. I've tried using the `#define FOO ...` syntax with floats and `#define FOO 0.5` but both fail, and have not found any more information on how I can possibly use floating point values in this manner. I'm trying to call functions from my C libraries from Python.

Is there a way to work around this limitation (if indeed it's a limitation) without touching the C code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only integers are supported.  For things like floats, there are two solutions:

1. You can of course write the constant as pure Python code, if it has a known value, and use that from the rest of your Python code.  In other words, put it outside CFFI.
2. This works in API mode: `static const float FOO;` declares `FOO` as something that can be read from in C, but not written to.